# Laravel 5.2 | Testing UploadedFile Misses the $test Value after Post. Bug?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, phpunit

##### Test Case

I create an instance of Symfony's UploadedFile class and I set `$test` to `true`. I post the file to `file/upload`.

```
class FileControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

    private $file;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->file = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(
            public_path() . '/examples/example.jpg',
            'example.jpg',
            'image/jpeg',
            filesize(public_path() . '/examples/example.jpg'),
            null,
            true // for $test
        );
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_uploads_a_valid_file()
    {
        var_dump($this->file); // $test = true
        $this->call('POST', 'file/upload', [], [], ['file' => $this->file],
            ['accept' => 'application/json']);

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

##### Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->file('file')); // $test = false

        return [];
    }
}
```

##### Problem

- The file to post has the argument `true` for `$test`
- The posted file arrives in `upload()`
- `$request->file('file')` contains the right arguments, but

**$test** is **false**

It seems the argument $test is not past by the post call. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Explanation

This is really interesting thing. You've noticed already a lot of when creating this post (if anyone has the problem should read it carefully).

In this [commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/5062a9b42632e55ee90b7397141c0b12622447e1) as you already mentioned `$testing` parameter was removed and code of classes was simplified removing Reflection to get `testing` property value of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`.

And now the tricky thing is that depending on what you are testing, you might event not notice the change and everything might work but in some cases it won't and you won't really know why.

For example everything might work - file will be uploaded without a problem, but if you add into your Request class for instance `mimes` rule like so:

```
'logo' => ['mimes:jpeg,png'],
```

it will fail telling you the file has invalid mime (this is because internally it will be also verified if file was really uploaded and in case of tests in fact it's not the same as real upload).

The solution is looking again at what was really changed into the commit and how the method look like. In [this file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5062a9b42632e55ee90b7397141c0b12622447e1/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php) instance of uploaded file is returned like so:

```
 return $file instanceof static ? $file : new static(
            $file->getRealPath(), $file->getClientOriginalName(), $file->getClientMimeType(),
            $file->getClientSize(), $file->getError()
        );
```

so in case if the file is instance of this class it will return this instance unmodified, otherwise it will create now object without passing `$testing` argument to class constructor.

## Solution

So to solve this, when testing file uploads you **should not use**

```
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
```

class anymore. You should now use

```
\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile
```

to don't get any strange issues when testing file uploads (of course you should still pass to this object constructor `true` as `$testing` parameter but now it will be used later without a problem)

Comment: @schellingerht No problem, I had the same issue today and was trying to figure out what's going on

Comment: Laravel is a great framework I been working on, but these breaking changes piss me off! I spent many hours to figure it out, in v5.2.0 was working perfectly after upgrade to 5.2.29 this error also happened on me, solved by using `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you have the mimeType and size variable the wrong way in the constructor.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan Why do you think so? Signature of constructor is `__construct($path, $originalName, $mimeType = null, $size = null, $error = null, $test = false)` so 1st is mime and then size

Comment: Thank you. They should have put this breaking change in the upgrade guide.