# Issue with file upload (UploadedFile) when testing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Background:
I have created a test class, which worked fine in laravel 5.1; but doesn't in laravel 5.2. This is because the "test" parameter for the file is lost.

I use a code below to create file request:

```
$this->dataFile = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(
    base_path('tests/files/datafiles/A.csv'), 'A.csv', 'text/csv', 13071, null, true
);
```

and I send it using $this->call()

```
$this->call('POST', '/uploadFile?token=' . $this->token, $params, [], ['file' => [$this->dataFile]], []);
```

The problem that I am having is that on receiving end the "test" parameters comes through us being false:

```
[0] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => A.csv
            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => text/csv
            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 13071
            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => D:\tests/files/datafiles/A.csv
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => A.csv
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

`\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`

To create the uploaded file instead of:

`\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`

See this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37306881/1835484