# Laravel 8 can not upload .apk file

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Laravel 8 cannot upload .apk files. I get the following error.

> [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
> 1

```
if ($request->hasFile('file_name')) {
    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);

    if ($check) {
        $fileNameToStore = $filenameWithExt;
        $path = $request->file('file_name')->storeAs('public/apkfile/', $fileNameToStore);
        $apkstore = Apkfile::find($apk->id);
        $apkstore->file_name = $fileNameToStore;
        $apkstore->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700851/11293507

Comment: Not working I have try
$request->hasFile('file_name') in this line files value is 0 instead of 1

Comment: can you share the github link of the project?

Comment: this error solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if($request->file('file_name')){
            $apk = Apkfile::create([
                'apk_name' => $request->apk_name,
                'package_name' => $request->package_name,
                'created_at'            => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at'            => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ]);
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $check=in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension);

            if ($check) {
                //$fileNameToStore = $filename. '.' . $extension;
                $fileNameToStore = $filenameWithExt;
                $path = $request->file('file_name')->storeAs('public/apkfile/', $fileNameToStore);
                $apkstore = Apkfile::find($apk->id);
                $apkstore->file_name = $fileNameToStore;
                $apkstore->save();
                return redirect()->route('admin.apk.index')->with('success', 'Apk Uploaded successfully');
            }
            else{
                return redirect()->route('admin.apk.index')->with('error', 'not upload unsuccessfully');
            }
```